# Encoding a C# string to a Google Maps API URL

Tags: c#, arrays, url, encoding

I am trying to encode a url that will work with google maps API

```
string rootURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
                        string[][] parms = new string[][] { new string[] { "Address", "3806", "Sterling Road", "Downers Grove", "IL" }, new string[] { "sensor", "false" } };
                        rootURL += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parms[]);
```

End result should look like this:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3806+Sterling+Road,+Downers+Grove,+IL&sensor=false

Not sure what I am implementing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try with this:

```
var firstPart = new string[] {"3806", "Sterling Road", "Downers Grove", "IL"};
var secondPart = string.Format("{0}={1}", "sensor","false");
var joinedFirstPart = string.Join(" ", firstPart);
//we want to encode only the parameters with white spaces
var encodedParams = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(joinedFirstPart);
var rootUrl = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&{1}", encodedParams, secondPart);
```